# No se detecta tabla vacía correctamente en PHP

Tags: php, html, web, vscode

tengo un código en PHP, pero quiero que a la hora de mostrar una tabla vacía salga un mensaje de "tabla vacía". Este es mi código:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if (empty($row)) {
    echo "Tabla vacia<br>";
    echo "<a href='app.php'>Volver</a>";
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<table><tr><td>Nombre:</td><td>$row[nombre]</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Email:</td><td>$row[email]</td></tr></table>";
}
echo "<a href='app.php'>Volver</a>";
}
```

El problema es que a la hora de introducir unos datos, el primer registro no se muestra. ¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que haces un **mysqli_fetch_array()** sustraes un valor al resultado de la consulta. La primera vez que lo haces es aquí:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

y luego vuelves a usar **$row** para ir sacando el resto de registros uno a uno dentro del bucle *while*, sobrescribiendo el primer **$row** que ya contenia el primer registro de la consulta.

Lo habitual es hacer algo así:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "Tabla vacia<br>";
    echo "<a href='app.php'>Volver</a>";
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre:</td>
        <td>$row[nombre]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td>$row[email]</td>
    </tr>
</table>";
    }
    echo "<a href='app.php'>Volver</a>";
}
```

De este modo compruebas el número de registros obtenidos con la consulta mediante el uso de [mysqli_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), y si es **0** entonces entra en el condicional de la tabla vacía, y en caso contrario iniciará el bucle con todos sus registros, incluido el primero, pues no ha sido sustraído antes.

**Nota:** He aplicado indentación al **echo** porque en mi opinión el código queda más limpio así, siguendo la estructura HTML correctamente, pero a nivel de funcionalidad es lo mismo que el tuyo con los dos *echo* que hacias.